# what exactly does parse_inputs in matlab do?

Tags: matlab

I am reading the cluster function in the bioinformatics toolbox of matlab now. See [cluster.m](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2009b/matlab/r2009b/toolbox/bioinfo/bioinfo/@phytree/cluster.m).

Now I am stucked with the fifth line of the following code.

```
function [clus, nclus, steps]=cluster(tr,v,varargin)
numBranches=size(tr.tree,1);
numLeaves=numBranches+1;
numLabels=numBranches+numLeaves;
[criteria, P, n]=parse_inputs(tr, numLeaves, varargin{:});
```

This is my error

> I got that varargin{:} is the variable number of arguments of the function.

But what exactly happened here? 
Thanks very much for your time and attention.

Comment: What parameters did you pass in? `varargin` says that there are optional variables afterwards. `varargin{:}` inputs all these variables into the `cluster` function.

Comment: I should also note that `varargin` is a cell containing these parameters

Comment: `parse_input`is a [local function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html). It's defined at the end of the file `cluster.m`

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Your guys are so nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a local function. Scroll down below to see it.

Whenever you see an unfamiliar function, type `which` followed by function name to check if it's a Matlab function; if it is, type `help` to get more info on how to use it, and if it isn't then that's your cue to go look for it in the code.

Also, Matlab's build-in functions don't use underscores in their naming (AFAIK), so that can be a dead giveaway that the function you're looking at isn't from Mathworks.

From the linked file:

```
function [criteria,P,n] = parse_inputs(tr,numLeaves,varargin)
% Parse the varargin parameter/value inputs

% Check that we have the right number of PVP inputs
if rem(numel(varargin),2)~= 0
    error('Bioinfo:phytree:cluster:IncorrectNumberOfArguments',...
        'Incorrect number of arguments to %s.',mfilename);
end

% The allowed inputs
okargs = {'criterion','distances','maxclust'};

% Set default values
P = squareform(pdist(tr)); % Pairwise distances, stored in square form 
                           % since it will be indexed by row and columns
n = inf; % default maximum number of clusters
criteria = 'm'; % maximum is default criteria

for j=1:2:numel(varargin)-1
    [k, pval] = bioinfoprivate.pvpair(varargin{j}, varargin{j+1}, okargs, ['phytree:' mfilename]);
    switch(k)
        case 1 % 'criterion'
            crits = {'maximum','average','median','silhouette','gain','ratio'};
            crit = strmatch(lower(pval),crits);
            if isempty(crit)
                error('Bioinfo:phytree:cluster:NotValidCriterion',...
                    'Not a valid criterion.')
            elseif numel(crit)>1
                error('Bioinfo:phytree:cluster:AmbiguousCriterion',...
                    'Ambiguous criterion.')
            else
                codes = 'madsgr';
                criteria = codes(crit);
            end
        case 2 % 'distances'
            if isnumeric(pval) && isequal(size(pval),[numLeaves,numLeaves]) && all(~diag(pval)) && isequal(pval,pval') 
                P = pval;
            elseif isnumeric(pval) && isvector(pval) && numel(pval)==(numLeaves*(numLeaves-1)/2)
                P = squareform(pval);
            else
                error('Bioinfo:phytree:cluster:InvalidDistances',...
                       'DISTANCES must be compatible to the output of SEQPDIST, PDIST, or PHYTREE/PDIST.') 
            end
        case 3 % 'maxclust'
            if ~isnumeric(pval) || ~isscalar(pval) || rem(pval,1) || pval<1
                 error('Bioinfo:phytree:cluster:InvalidMaxClust',...
                       'MAXCLUST must be a positive integer.')
            end
            n = pval;
    end
end
```